# Enable Cors .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, f#, cors

In C# using WebApi2 I defined the following endpoint using `WebApi2`:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "Post", SupportsCredentials = true)]
[HttpPost]
[Route("myRouting")]
public HttpResponseMessage MyEndPoint()
{
    //...some code
}
```

and it works by calling it with:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.withCredentials = true;
request.send();
```

Trying to upgrade it to F# .Net Core w/o success:

```
let webApp =
    choose [
        route "/" >=> text "Description"
        POST >=> routef "myRouting" myEndPoint ]

let configureCors (builder : CorsPolicyBuilder) =
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .WithMethods("POST")
           .AllowCredentials()
           |> ignore

let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    app.UseCors(configureCors)
       .UseGiraffe webApp

let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddCors()
            .AddGiraffe() |> ignore
```

Getting the error *The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.*

I know about *Specifying AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials is an insecure configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both methods.*

Why does it work with `WebApi2` and is there a way to get it to work without specifying any origin?

Comment: If you try .AllowAnyMethod() does it work? You might need to allow "OPTIONS" method

Comment: Well, I don't get a 405 on the preflight. Actually there isn't a preflight at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a policy when using the `services.AddCors` method in the `configureServices` function.  Here's an equivalent example using your configuration adapted from a working F# .NET Core Web API I'm using in production:

```
let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddCors(fun options -> 
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", fun builder -> 
                 builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .WithMethods("POST")
                        .AllowCredentials() |> ignore))
            .AddGiraffe()
            |> ignore
```